# How would you notifiy clients about changed data on the server using .Net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, events, remoting, client-server

Imagine a WinForms client app that displays fairly complex calculated data fetched from a server app with .Net Remoting over a HTTPChannel.
Since the client app might be running for a whole workday, I need a method to notify the client that new data is available so the user is able to start a reload of the data when he needs to.
Currently I am using remoted .Net events, serializing the event to the client and then rethrowing the event on the side of the client.

I am not very happy with this setup and plan to reimplement it.
Important for me is:

- .Net 2.0 based technology
- easy of use
- low complexity
- robust enough to survive a server or client restart still functional

When limited to .Net 2.0, how would you implement such a feature? What technologies / libraries would you use?
I am looking for inspiration on how to attack the problem.

Edit:

The client and server exist in the same organisation, typically a LAN, perhaps a WAN/VPN situation.
This mechanism should only make the client aware that there is new data available. I'd like to keep remoting for getting the actual data to the client since that is working pretty well. MSMQ comes with windows, doesn't it? So it should be ok to use it, but I'm open to any alternative.

Comment: Are the clients internal to your organisation/external? Have you got some control over the environment e.g. MSMQ? How much data are you transferring?

Comment: MSMQ would be ideal, in this case.  It can be installed on a server or client without a restart.  Also, if AD is available you have more options for queue lookup, discovery, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a similar notification mechanism using MSMQ.  The client machine opens a local, public queue, and then advises the server of it's queue name.  When changes occur, the server pushes notifications into all the client queues that it's be made aware of.  This way the client will know that data is ready, even if it wasn't running when the notification was sent.

The only downside is that it requires MSMQ on the clients, so this may not work if you don't have that kind of control over your client's machines.

For an extra level of redundancy (for example, if a client machine is completely down, and therefore the client queue is unavailable) you could queue notifications on the server prior to dissemination to clients.  Notifications in the server queues are only removed when the client is successfully contacted (or perhaps after 3 failed attempts, etc.)

Also in that regard, if the server fails to deliver messages to a client a measured number of times, over a measured period of time, then support entities are notified, error alerts go out, and the client queue is removed from the list of destinations.  When I say "measured" I mean a frequency/duration that makes sense to the setting.  In my case, it was 5 retries with 5 minute intervals between attempts.

It might also make sense to have the client "renew" it's notification subscription at intervals.  If a renewal doesn't occur, then eventually the client queue is removed from the destination list by a "groomer" process in the service.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into into it. If the clients publish their queue to the server, wont there be the chance of lost queue references on the server, if the client go offline without notifying the server?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you need to implement a message-queue based solution. Easy to implement, can survive reboots, and the technology is mature both on the server (MSMQ, MGQSeries) and on the client (System.Messaging)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find anything built-in and assuming you know the address of all the clients, you could send them a UDP message when data changes. Using UdpClient, this is very easy. The datagram doesn't even need to contain any data if the client app can assume that any UDP data on a certain port means it needs to get new data from the server.

If necessary, you can even make this a broadcast packet (if you don't know who the clients are and they are on the same subnet as the server), so long as the server isn't too "chatty".

Whatever solution you decide on, I would urge you to avoid having the clients poll. This will create a lot of unecessary network traffic and still won't perform all that well.

Answer (score -1):

I would usually use a UI timer on the client to periodically hit the server to see if there was new or updated data.  (Assuming you have a mechanism to identify that you have new data like time stamps for new rows, or file time stamps, or a table with last-calculated dates, etc)

That way the server doesn't have to know about the clients.  The clients can check at their leisure, etc.

Comment: I get -1?  It's essentially the same idea as tamberg upthread.  The clients should be polling for new data.  Having the server contact the client is not very robust.  Stateless servers are better for this.  Give me the date of the last update.  Give me the data.  You code those two and you're set.